# t-sql bulk import directory path as variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a bunch of files I want to import into a SQL Server database - how can I achieve something similar to the following where the directory is a variable:

```
DECLARE @Directory VARCHAR(256)
SET @Directory = 'C:\some\directory\name\'

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
    BULK @Directory + 'importfile.txt',
    FORMATFILE = @Directory +'importfileFormatFile.Xml'
) AS t1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
DECLARE @Directory VARCHAR(256);
SET @Directory = 'C:\some\directory\name\';
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = '
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @Directory + 'importfile.txt'',
                    FORMATFILE = '''+@Directory +'importfileFormatFile.Xml''
                   ) AS t1
';

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Linnoff thanks mate that's perfect - just made a quick edit too many single quotes after filenames.